# How to deserialize JSON in my web service POST method

Tags: c#, json, web-services, json.net

My web service receives data-filtering values in JSON format. Here is an example of how the filtering criteria is sent:

```
var jsonString = {
"startDate":"2015-01-19T15:04:54.897Z",
"endDate":"2016-01-19T15:04:54.897Z",
"filterParams":{
    "facilityIds":
        [
            {"ID":1,"charID":"1","Description":"Health Group Umbrella Organization","DoubleValue1":35.009803,"DoubleValue2":85.21,"StringValue1":""},
            {"ID":2,"charID":"2","Description":"Main Hospital Organization","DoubleValue1":35.04,"DoubleValue2":89.3,"StringValue1":""},
            {"ID":3,"charID":"3","Description":"Regional Medical Center","DoubleValue1":35.04,"DoubleValue2":89.30,"StringValue1":""}
        ],                      
    "GenderIds":[{"ID":0,"charID":"F","Description":"Female","DoubleValue1":0,"DoubleValue2":0,"StringValue1":""}],
    "AgeRangeIds":[{"ID":4,"charID":"4","Description":"30 - 34","DoubleValue1":0,"DoubleValue2":0,"StringValue1":""}],
    "HomeownerIds":[{"ID":7,"charID":"7","Description":"More Likely Owner 1","DoubleValue1":0,"DoubleValue2":0,"StringValue1":""}],
    "IncomeRangeIds":[{"ID":3,"charID":"3","Description":"$30,001 - $40,000","DoubleValue1":0,"DoubleValue2":0,"StringValue1":""}],
    "HasChildrenIds":[{"ID":0,"charID":"N","Description":"No","DoubleValue1":0,"DoubleValue2":0,"StringValue1":null}],
    "EncoutnerTypesIds":
        [
            {"ID":2,"charID":"2","Description":"Ambulatory","DoubleValue1":0,"DoubleValue2":0,"StringValue1":""},
            {"ID":1,"charID":"1","Description":"InPatient","DoubleValue1":0,"DoubleValue2":0,"StringValue1":""},
            {"ID":3,"charID":"3","Description":"Emergency","DoubleValue1":0,"DoubleValue2":0,"StringValue1":""},
            {"ID":4,"charID":"4","Description":"Office Visit","DoubleValue1":0,"DoubleValue2":0,"StringValue1":""}
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm able to pull out the startDate and endDate no problem:

```
var jsonValues = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);            
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(jsonValues["startDate"] as string);
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse(jsonValues["endDate"] as string);
```

However, I just can't seem to figure out how to handle the "filterParams" portion of the JSON. It should map to the class structure:

```
public class FilterModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public char charID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double DoubleValue1 { get; set; }
    public double DoubleValue2 { get; set; }
    public string StringValue1 { get; set; }
}
```

the following statement populates the variable with the correct data but I'm unable to access the values.

```
var filterParams = jsonValues["filterParams"];
```

I need to somehow deserialize the data into a `Dictionary<string, FilterModel>` but the Deserialize method requires a string param and filterParams is an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to deserialize each property manually...

## JavaScriptSerializer

You can deserialize it directly to a complex object using the native `JavaScriptSerializer`:

```
RootObject obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

## Newtonsoft Json

Or as @Wobbles suggested, you can use the `Json.Net` also known as [Newtonsoft Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

It is faster and has more features than `JavaScriptSerializer` as you can see [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonNetVsDotNetSerializers.htm).

Comment: I would even suggest json.net, little better

Comment: I wrapped all 3 parts into a FilterCriteria class (startDate, endDate, and filterParams). I also change filterParams to Dictionary<string, int[]> and chagned my JavaScript to only pass an array of ints for filterParams instead of the entire complex FilterModel structure. Then I used Newtonsoft Json to deserialize the JSON - worked like a charm. Thanks to both of you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this (Very specific, but it must works):

-> This is using Newtonsoft

```
    public class YourJson
    {
        public DateTime startDate;
        public DateTime endDate;
        public FilterParams filterParams;
    }

    public class FilterParams
    {
        public __ID[] facilityIds;
        public __ID[] GenderIds;
        public __ID[] AgeRangeIds;
        public __ID[] HomeownerIds;
        public __ID[] IncomeRangeIds;
        public __ID[] HasChildrenIds;
        public __ID[] EncoutnerTypesIds;
    }

    public class __ID
    {
        public int ID;
        public char charID;
        public string Description;
        public double DoubleValue1;
        public double DoubleValue2;
        public String StringValue1;
    }

    var yourJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourJson>(json);
```